Why Blender Installer is asking strange app to be allowed?
Whenever I'm trying to install Blender on Windows 11, the installer is popping a screen asking if I'm sure to let this app "<random letters and number>.msi" make changes. The name of the app is always different and same thing happens while uninstalling too. The certificate however shows as verified. I tried downloading from different official mirrors but the same issue continues. What app is this and what is its purpose?


That is normal behavour. The .msi file is a Microsoft installer file which is extracted and run when you run the Blender install. It needs to be run as Administrator under Windows, hence the warning.

@JohnEason I understand it's some sort of installer file, but what is this weird naming every time and what it has to do with blender?

The message you're seeing during Blender's installation is due to the User Account Control (UAC) feature, which prevents unauthorized changes by asking for permission with each action. The seemingly random .msi filenames are temporary files created by the Windows Installer service. The verified certificate from "Stichting Blender Foundation" confirms the installer's legitimacy. It's safe to install if you downloaded it from the official website.

Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see How to take a screenshot. Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.
